# Java message formatting

Tags: java

I am formatting my messages in a properties file, but in order to display the desired message fragments I need to validate the arguments... By validate I mean NOT NULL..

ex.
LOCATION_NOT_FOUND=Unable to find State: {0} {display only if {1} not null, city:{1}}.

desired output would be- "Unable to find State:New Jersey"
if city is not null - "Unable to find State:New Jersey, city:Trenton"

i was thinking about using {1,choice, notnull#city{1}}, but I have no clue if this is correct...

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2):

I would have two different messages:

```
LOCATION_NOT_FOUND_STATE=...
LOCATION_NOT_FOUND_STATE_AND_CITY=...
```

then format the appropriate one based on what non-null values you have.